# What is "redirect write" in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, entra-id

I'm looking at setting up ADConnect to sync users into ADAzure and found the following warning:

- Azure AD Connect does not follow any write redirects

On the follow page:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-prerequisites

I have never encountered "write redirects" and was only able to find the following that loosly relates but doesn't help me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203661/openldap-redirect-on-write

I'm guessing that its a part of the LDAP spec the AD implements.

I would like if:

1. a couple of example use cases to help me understand write redirects (this is becasue i don't know how to narrow my question yet)?
2. How to create a write redirect?
3. What are the implications of creating a write redirect?
4. If you know, is it common to create write redirects?

For context i need to be able to comunicate requirments for my organisations software and without understanding about "write redirect" i don't know if its relivent or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-prerequisites - "The domain controller used by Azure AD must be writable. It is not supported to use a **RODC (read-only domain controller)** and Azure AD Connect does not follow any write redirects."

This statement is only applicable if you have **RODC's**. 
If an application needs write access to Active Directory objects, the RODC will send an LDAP referral response that redirects the application to a writable domain controller (aka write redirect). When setting up ADConnect be sure to point it at one of your writable DCs, typically the one holding the PDC Role if you're using Password writeback.

More info on RODC's if interested - https://4sysops.com/archives/windows-server-2008-read-only-domain-controller-rodc/